# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://...' in Google App Engine PHP App

Tags: php, google-app-engine, soap, wsdl

I am trying to connect to Amazon Web Services from my GAE account using a simple PHP script. However, the very first line is throwing an error:

$wsdlURI = 'http://www.webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl';
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlURI);

I get this error:
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://.....'failed to load external entity

When I do a simple file_get_contents on the above URL, it works just fine. Only the SoapClient is not able to get the handle on the wsdl file....and ONLY GAE seems to have this problem. I tried the same code on another server and everything works fine.

Is there any setting in GAE that I am missing??

Answer (score 2):

This is also related to the disabling of loading of loading of external entities by default, you will need to enable this to get this to work.

First, you must create a php.ini file containing this line:

```
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "libxml_disable_entity_loader"
```

Then you add the following before your call.

```
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
```

For SoapClient to work using sockets application also needs to have billing enabled.

Comment: This solved the error I was getting with GAE, now getting "Could not connect to host(HTTP)" I believe Sockets API is needed in GAE. You need to enable billing and request access to Sockets API

Comment: yep you need to enable billing on the app to use sockets. you still get the free quotas, but you need to have billing enabled.

Comment: I have billing enabled but still getting the error. my wsdl url is https so it may be an SSL issue with GAE? Can you confirm you are actually using soap with GAE successfully?

Comment: definitely using SoapClient with GAE

Answer (score 0):

This issue is likely related: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9858 .
Looks like SOAP needs sockets support, which is not yet part of the PHP runtime.

Comment: I thought as much....the error is completely replicated when the code is run on my local machine through the GAE PHP SDK. So I am assuming that the PHP that is bundled with the SDK is exactly the same as the one on the deployment server, right? On the other hand, not allowing a SOAP client to specify its wsdl URI is funny because GAE has enabled SOAP but not socket support without which soap wouldn't work anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the following extensions activated:
php open ssl 
and 
php soap client.